# Problem with Maximize command in Mathematica

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am new to Mathematica, and don't understand what is wrong with this command. In any of these inputs, the output is just a copy of what I wrote as an input. 
Thanks a lot for your help.

```
F[h_, x_] := CDF[NormalDistribution[h, σ], x] 
Obj[k, q, p] := F[k - q, q - p] (p - q^2/2) 
Maximize[Obj[k, q, p] , q] 
Maximize[1/2 (p - q^2/2) Erfc[(k + p - 2 q)/(Sqrt[2] σ)], q] 
Maximize[ 1/2 (p - q^2/2) Erfc[(k + p - 2 q)/(Sqrt[2] σ)], q, {p > 0, q > 0}] 

(* Out: Maximize[ 1/2 (p - q^2/2) Erfc[(k + p - 2 q)/(Sqrt[2] σ)], q, {p > 0, q > 0}] *)

Obj[k, q, p] 
(* Out: 1/2 (p - q^2/2) Erfc[(k + p - 2 q)/(Sqrt[2] σ)] *)
```

Comment: Lisa, thank you for adding the code. I formatted it and added it to your question. You can always edit your question yourself using the "edit" link right below it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @MarcoB

Answer (score 3):

There may be nor general analytic solution. You only get results, if you feed in numerical values for p,k,sigma.

```
F[h_, x_, \[Sigma]_] = CDF[NormalDistribution[h, \[Sigma]], x]

Obj[k_, q_, p_, \[Sigma]_] = F[k - q, q - p, \[Sigma]] (p - q^2/2)

max[p_, k_, \[Sigma]_] := 
   Maximize[{Obj[k, q, p, \[Sigma]], 0 < q < 10}, q]
```

Even simple Maximize yields complicated root-objects.

```
max[1, 1, 1]

(*   {-(1/4) Erfc[(1/Sqrt[
      2])(2 - 2 Root[{-2 Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] + 
      E^(2 (-1 + #1)^2) Erfc[(2 - 2 #1)/Sqrt[2]] #1 + 
      Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] #1^2 &, 0.94919764352934575212}])] (-2 + 
   Root[{-2 Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] + 
    E^(2 (-1 + #1)^2) Erfc[(2 - 2 #1)/Sqrt[2]] #1 + 
    Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] #1^2 &, 0.94919764352934575212}]^2), {q -> 
   Root[{-2 Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] + 
   E^(2 (-1 + #1)^2) Erfc[(2 - 2 #1)/Sqrt[2]] #1 + 
   Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] #1^2 &, 0.94919764352934575212}]}}   *)
```

Numerical maximisation is faster

```
nmax[p_, k_, \[Sigma]_] := NMaximize[Obj[k, q, p, \[Sigma]], q]

Plot3D[First@nmax[p, k, 1], {p, 0, 1}, {k, 0, 1}]
```

[image]